# How to use docker compose watch to sync environment variables change

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker compose watch with compose.yaml file and everything is configured to rebuild on env file change. However, although the image rebuilds and the container is being restarted, environment variables are not changed. Is there a way to do it with watch directive or maybe I would need to use watchtower(just read about it)?

Here is part of my compose.yaml file.

```
  develop:
    watch:
      - action: rebuild
        path: dotenvs/.nginx.env
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Docker Compose does not automatically update environment variables in running containers when the environment file changes.

Docker Compose and a tool like envsubst to update environment variables in your container when the environment file changes.